# Error while installing (bootstrapping) latest Spark on latest AWS EMR (5.13.X)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I have been trying to install Spark on latest EMR((5.13.X)cluster via bootstrapping using the following with Terraform, but not getting successful. Any ready to use latest Spark/emr version bootable script or other solution to do using Terraform?

```
   bootstrap_action = {
path = "s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark"
name = "install-spark"
args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

That install-spark bootstrap action hasn't worked since before Spark was officially supported as an application on AMI version 3.9.0 about three years ago. Also, bootstrap actions built for AMI version 3.x and earlier do not work at all with release labels emr-4.x and emr-5.x+.

Instead, to install Spark on emr-4.x or emr-5.x, you simply include "Spark" in the list of Applications of the RunJobFlowRequest.

I have not used Terraform to create an EMR cluster, but the example I found at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html shows exactly how to create a cluster with Spark.